# How to update Angular named route param after data arrives

Tags: angularjs, routes

I have something like

```
angular.module('MyApp.routing', []).
    config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/",
        {action: "home"})

        .when("/calculator/:slug/:docId/:versionId",
        {action: "calculator", reloadOnSearch: false})

        .otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
}]);
```

in my routing file. I make a request to backend API in my controller and I want to update URL slug param.

```
$scope.initPage = function () {
    $scope.content = {};
    $scope.isPreloaderVisible = true;
    http.post("calculator.getContentData.angular",
        {'slug': $scope.slug, 'docId': $scope.docId, 'versionId': $scope.versionId}, getContentSuccess, getContentErrorHandler);
}
```

To summarize, I use URL like:

```
http://localhost/#/calculator//123456/
```

and I want to update it (without reload a whole page) to:

```
http://localhost/#/calculator/slug/123456/
```

in method getContentSuccess after request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any route change i believe cause view (defined in ng-view) to update itself. The `reloadOnSearch` is a parameter which is applicable to `search` parameters which are basically `querystring` parameters.

So if you can make your slug as part of querystring instead of url path you can stop view change.

Or else you need to look at other routing library like [ui-route](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)